# How to mock the interface using mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a method in the class I am testing that has a getInterface method that returns the interface using that, all the get methods in the interface are called.

e.g.

```
Interface: Foo
Method in interface: getSomething()
```

The class:

```
getFoo(){
return foo;
}
```

then in the main method it has getFoo().getSomethind();

I need to mock the foo interface then set

```
 Mockito.when(getFoo().getSomething()).thenReturn(something);
```

I was wondering how to do this as I am geting the TargetException here when I do:

```
    @Mock
    Foo foo;
    Mockito.when(getFoo()).thenReturn(foo);
    Mockito.when(getFoo().getSomething()).thenReturn("result");
```

Comment: You're not supplying a target, just a function; the target for the interface is `foo.getSomething()`, the target for the `getFoo` call is `whateverYoureMocking.getFoo()`, no? Hard to say without the surrounding context.

Comment: The getFoo() method resides in the class I am testing and returns the interface

Comment: Yes, I see that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this. You should create an mock of the Interface and inject this mock implementation into class under test:

```
public interface Foo {
    String getSomething();
}

public class SampleClass {

   private final Foo foo;

   public SampleClass(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }
}
```

Now in order to test the class `SampleClass`:

```
public class SampleClassTest {

    @Mock
    Foo foo;
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
       // setup:
       Mockito.when(foo.getSomething()).thenReturn("whatever");
       SampleClass underTest = new SampleClass(foo);
        
       // when:
       underTest.callSomeBusinessMethod(); // this inside should call foo.getSomething() 
       // then:
       ... assert the results ...
           
    }
}
```

Now what confuses me in your question is that you're running `getFoo().getSomething()` from the main method. In this case the question is what exactly is the scope of your test? Are you testing the code of the main method? If so, you can't really inject anything to it becuase its an entry point - it's kind of inconsistent with classic mocking techniques.

If this is indeed what you need, consider refactoring the Main method - extract it's code to some real (non static) method of the class and test this class's behaviour. Main won't be covered by unit test, but it will contain one line of code exactly:

```
public class MyEntryPoint {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass(new FooImpl());
     sampleClass.doThis();
     sampleClass.doThat();
   }
}

Should be refactored to:

// this can be tested as well
public class SampleProcExecution {
   private final SampleClass sampleClass;
   ... constructor ...
   public void execute() {
     sampleClass.doThis();
     sampleClass.doThat();
  }
}

public class MyEntryPoint {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      new SampleProcExecion(new SampleClass(new 
      FooImpl()).execute();
        
   }
}
```

In real life instead of doing initializing the dependencies in the main class (see the refactored version) you'll better off by using Dependency injection container (Spring, Google Guice, etc). This is much better because you won't manage the dependencies in code, but its beyond the scope of the question.